# How to remove pair duplication in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have dataset, the dataset have pairing duplication. Here's my data

```
Id    antecedent           descendant
1     one                  two
2     two                  one
3     two                  three
4     one                  three
5     three                two
```

Here's what I need, because `one, two` is equals `two, one` so I want ro remove the duplicate pair

```
Id    antecedent           descendant
1     one                  two
3     two                  three
4     one                  three
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for sort per rows with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for boolean mask:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['antecedent','descendant']], axis=1))
```

Or:

```
#slowier solution
#df1 = df[['antecedent','descendant']].apply(frozenset, 1)
```

---

```
df = df[~df1.duplicated()]
print (df)
   Id antecedent descendant
0   1        one        two
2   3        two      three
3   4        one      three
```